# How to use HttpTestingController expectNone?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I am trying to verify that a specific url has NOT been called via HTTP GET using Angular 8. If I were testing the opposite, I would write the following:

```
myService.retrieveData().subscribe(data => {
    expect(data).toEqual(myMockData);
});

const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(myUrl);
expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
req.flush(myMockData);
```

But I am trying to now implement httpTestingController.expectNone(myUrl) , but what would I put as my expect? The goal with this is that I have an if statement that looks like the following that I am trying to test:

```
if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId) {
    return this.http.get(myUrl);
}
```

But Istanbul is reporting that I have not tested the else path. Ideas?

Comment: There is no else part, so your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: I agree with JB, add your `service.ts` code and then the `spec` code

Comment: I would also encourage you to read my articles https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7 which covers all basic testing scenarios. Feel free to provide feedback on it as well :)  Cheers !\

Comment: I figured this out. You don't actually need a separate expect, just putting httpTestingController.expectNone(myUrl) is the test itself, so I just mocked the return value of isPlatformBrowser to be false and did the expect none and it gave me my code coverage.